# Javafx - Resizable UI that works outside a Tab doesn't when put inside a Tab

Tags: javafx, tabs, javafx-8

Is there any reason that a FXML that resizes nicely when put in it's own stage, does not resize properly when put in a TabPane? It resizes horizontally fine, but vertically it doesn't act the same.

I used the fx:include method to include various controls with their own controllers as Tabs.

I have tried changing the root Pane type of each but nothing seems to help it resize in a Tab.

Any advice on this problem? I can't be the only one.

Comment: The difference in behavior is that if you set an element as the root of the scene, it will expand to fill the entire scene, regardless of any min/pref/max width and height settings you define on it (or that it has by default). If you place an element in a layout pane, or other control such as `TabPane` that manages layout, then the layout pane will make a best effort to size it to its preferred size, and will respect any min/max size settings. Obviously it's impossible to be more specific about what's happening unless you provide a [MCVE].

Comment: After more trying things out, the problem is related to using the include tag for the tab contents. If I manually load the FXML and add the Tab programmatically, then the tab contents does resize correctly. So why would includes not resize correclty is now the real question?